# Where to get bow saw 42 inch?

Tags: wood, hand-tools

I cannot find anywhere bow saw frame for 42 inch blade. Could you advise?
Many thanks,
Martin

Comment: Found a complete 42 inch bow saw in an antique store and bought it. I had been looking for 1 for several years. I put anew blade in it and what a saw!

Answer (score 5):

These days I think most bow-saw frames are made by the woodworker and not bought, although that may be just what is common in Western Europe and North America.

If making your own sounds like a project you'd be interested in here is a plan you can use as a starting point, scaling up as needed for the length of your saw blade:

[image: Bow saw plan]

For greater details of a different frame style look at this article on Popular Woodworking, [Make a Shapely Bowsaw](http://www.popularwoodworking.com/article/make-a-shapely-bowsaw-2).

Another option to consider which vastly simplifies the making of one is simply by fitting the blade to two ends of a bent branch:

[image: Branch bow saw]

<sup>Source: [FAT GUYS IN THE WOODS: BLOG SKILL SERIES: Make an Improvised Bow Saw](http://willowhavenoutdoor.com/featured-wilderness-survival-blog-entries/fat-guys-in-the-woods-blog-skill-series-make-an-improvised-bow-saw/)</sup>

Comment: Note that old bandsaw blades can sometimes make decent bow saw blades, especially if you spend some time sharpening and setting the teeth appropriately.

Comment: With wooden bow saw you can start with standard length saw (e.g. 700mm) and replace stretcher (elem. B on the schematic above) with one matching you blade length.